# Problem with SOQL multilevel relationship query returning one column for two fields

Tags: soql

I am having trouble with the output of an SOQL multilevel relationship query:

```
SELECT
Flight__c.Related_Case__r.Related_Success_Story__r.Sharing_Permission__c,
Flight__c.Related_Case__r.Related_Success_Story__r.Sharing_Notes__c
FROM Flight__c
```

`Flight__C` is the grandchild

`Case` is the Parent

The query runs fine but it returns a single column called – `Related_Case__r.Related_Success_Story__r`

It contains the results from BOTH fields – `Sharing_Permission__c` and `Sharing_Notes__c` in the same column.

I don’t understand why this isn’t returning two separate columns for each field. I am noticing that whenever I try to create a relationship query of over two levels the column output does not include the field name, just the relationship path.

Comment: Where are you consuming this query. It does return both fields. But if you were consuming the record in JSON or some other areas, the field path would consolidate.

Comment: or if you run it from Developer Console it also shows as 1 column (while there's actually data for both in the query result)

Comment: I ran it in the Developer Console but I am trying to get it to export into Google Sheets and it is returning the data from both fields into the one column. The issue is that I am trying to fix something that was done previously and at one point it was exporting into Sheets as separate fields but when I use the same query that was used previously it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

This is both the result of design desicions made by Salesforce, and an artifact of whatever approach you're using to turn the data into a string.

#### Some background

If you have experience with other programming languages and have used a database in a project before, it shouldn't be a surprise that there is (in many cases) a difference in how programming language represents/works with data, and how a database represents/works with data. ORMs (Object-Relational Mappers) help hide the complexity in going to/from the database, and let us (programmers) just focus on working with data instead of trying to transform it.

For all of the complaints that we might have with Salesforce/Apex, one thing I think they've done exceptionally well is integrating SObjects (i.e. database tables), queries (mainly through SOQL and SOSL), and code. There's definitely some ORM-style mapping happening somewhere, but it's transparent to us.

#### What this means for us

Data on related records (e.g. the Name of an Account that an Opportunity is related to through the `AccountId` field) **gets stored in an embedded `SObject`** when you are querying from a child record to a parent record (e.g. Opportunity -> Account, the "child" is always the one that contains the relationship field),
and in an embedded `List<SObject>` when you're querying from a parent record to child record(s).

They're always fully-fledged SObjects (or a list thereof), which allows us to access the data in the same way as if you were working through any other "Object" (in the "Object-Oriented Programming" sense), dot notation.

The way you'd access the data *is exactly the same way that you queried it*. E.g. your query has `Related_Case__r.Related_Success_Story__r.Sharing_Permission__c`, so when you go to use the result of your query, you'd access that data like `myFlight.Related_Case__r.Related_Success_Story__r.Sharing_Permission__c`

Same goes for Sharing_Notes__c.

Since these are nested objects, whenever you want to do something like a `system.debug()`, Salesforce needs to know how to turn your object(s) into a printable string (a process called "serialization"). The default serialization approach will leave out data on related records and collapse it down to just the `__r` "field" (but it's really an SObject). Something similar also happens when you execute a query through the developer console.

*The data is still there*, and you can still use it.

If you want a serialization that includes more (all) of the related data, then the easiest option is probably to serialize the query result as JSON. E.g.

```java
Opportunity opp = [SELECT Id, Name, StageName, Account.Name, Account.CreatedDate FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = '006000000000001'];
system.debug(JSON.serialize(opp));
```

Comment: My issue is that this same query was used to export data into a Google Sheet and it apparently gave the output in two different columns as of a few months ago. I am just trying to recreate it but I cannot get that to happen.